# How can I show the hmtl tags in my browser output in php?

Tags: php, html, tags, command, output

I have:

```
$xml="<number>" . $number->number . "</number>"
```

in PHP and want to show it in my browser output with all the `<number></number>` tags, how is this possible? Can't find the right command for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do like this:

```
foreach($numbers as $number){
?>
<number><?= $number ?></number>
<?php
}
```

This will show all the values of $numbers variable in the  html tag.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the default header (text/html) so that your browser know that you are going to output XML content :

```
 <?php
 header("Content-type: application/xml");

 $numbers = array(1,2,3);
 echo "<numbers>";

 foreach($numbers as $number){

     echo "<number>$number</number>";
 }
 echo "</numbers>";
```